# UIKit -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash-reports

I ran into a very unusual problem.. i got a crash on UIKit.. first time i have faced something like this.. Please can anybody guide my in this..

This is the crash log that i got.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x1161a18c

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x386fcb66 objc_msgSend + 5
1  UIKit                          0x30b5dda3 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 90
2  UIKit                          0x30cc5615 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 120
3  UIKit                          0x30b5dda3 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 90
4  UIKit                          0x30b5dd3f -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 38
5  UIKit                          0x30b5dd13 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 46
6  UIKit                          0x30b49743 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 374
7  UIKit                          0x30b5d75b -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 594
8  UIKit                          0x30b5d425 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 528
9  UIKit                          0x30b58451 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 832
10 UIKit                          0x30b2dd79 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 196
11 UIKit                          0x30b2c569 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7116
12 CoreFoundation                 0x2e36ff1f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
13 CoreFoundation                 0x2e36f3e7 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 206
14 CoreFoundation                 0x2e36dbd7 __CFRunLoopRun + 630
15 CoreFoundation                 0x2e2d8471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
16 CoreFoundation                 0x2e2d8253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
17 GraphicsServices               0x330122eb GSEventRunModal + 138
18 UIKit                          0x30b8d845 UIApplicationMain + 1136
19 TradeMate                      0x0008f2bf main (main.m:16)
```

Comment: How you are getting this error?Please include the steps or you are getting this error on starting the application.

Comment: this came unexpectedly.. don't know how i got that...

Comment: Try using exception breakpoint http://stackoverflow.com/a/17802942/397915

Comment: i got this report from an app running at my client's device.. i couldn't reproduce it here on my own device so no good using exception breakpoints.

Comment: probably related: [EXC_BAD_ACCESS with IBACTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070204/exc-bad-access-with-ibaction)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are crashing in `objc_msgSend`. This means (as explained in this [famous article](http://sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/09/22/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend.html)) that the receiver has gone missing. In this case it appears that the user has tapped a button which sends an action message to a target, but the target object has gone out of existence.

Comment: What is solution for same?

Comment: Even if you know the reason that triggered this crash, it's difficult to locate in specific lines. it drives me crazy. in my case, it only happens on iOS8, and we can't reproduce it .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the receiver or the object which receives the events is declared strong.
You may not even get the crash log to figure out what what went wrong :)

[image]

If you are getting something like above check if the object is declared strong. That should solve the issue