# UIKit: -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 100 Crash

Tags: ios, swift, crash, uikit

I've had some crash reports back from my app in the organiser tool in Xcode. The greatest number of crash's for my app are with

> **UIKit: -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 100.**

I'm not sure what this crash relates to but it does seem its a UIKit issue? Could really appreciate your help as i'm new to iOS development and feel quite stuck with this one.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241484/uikit-uiapplication-sendactiontofromforevent-crash

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I've checked my view controller code and all my IB outlets for button actions are declared strong. I'm not sure why there could be a issue with deallocation? Could you offer any advice on how to work through the error to resolve it?

Comment: are you removed the any subview from superview using removefromsuperView function in anywhere in your project

Comment: Hi. No I've not got any removefromsuperview. I've got a view controller made up on the storyboard with a viewcontroller.swift file which has the IBOutlets. I have two buttons both declared strong with actions associated. My app had a one star review with the comment that it keeps crashing when pressing the buttons and this was the crash report. The app works fine on my test phone (iPhone 6) and also on the simulator... Looking at the crash reports on the organiser in Xcode about 46 phones have had this crash.

Comment: can you show your crash report we can identify

Comment: I've added the crash report to the initial question listing...

Comment: can you add the elobrate crash report, it is easy to identify which fucntionalities it is crashed

Comment: It doesn't show a elaborate crash report in the organiser crash section of Xcode. when i open it in the project it doesn't show any more detail really. hard to get a clear view of whats happening.. do you know were you can get at a more detailed crash report?